# Phyre engine to xna

Tags: xna, xbox, steam, playstation3

If I build a game/program with phyre engine, will I be able to use it on xna without a workload of recoding? And is it ok that phyre is coded in c++ while xna is c#, and then subsequently onto steam.

Need to have a game released vis psn, xbox, and steam.

Comment: No, you won't be able to.

Comment: Dang, how would i release it on all 3 platforms then? Would i habe to code on phyre engine and seperatly on xna?

Comment: it seems like the engine can run on pc as well (backed by opengl or directx), but xbox seems out of the question. After all, phyre is a sony product, xbox is a microsoft one. Can't expect it to run on a competitor's product.

Comment: Haha ya that makes sense, do you know if there is a cross platform developer I could use? Or just have to bite the bullet and recode for different consoles. Thanks

Comment: @Femaref FWIW, although PhyreEngine is indeed a Sony product, and we don't/can't support certain other platforms 'out of the box', it has been successfully ported to them and we support/encourage such porting.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to, they are two completely different engines.